# Coolant still disappears and overheating after head gasket change

Tags: toyota, overheating, coolant-leak, tacoma

I have a 1997 toyota Tacoma 2wd. I had the head gasket replaced. I'm still loosing coolant. Then I was told to replace the thermostat, still loosing coolant. Someone else told me to replace the radiator cap, still loosing coolant and temperature going high. Please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: So perhaps it is not only the head gasket at fault, or even not the head gasket at all. Have you inspected the radiator for signs of leaks? Have you had it pressure tested? Are the hoses in good condition? Seen a pin-hole been the source of a leak and it only happened at full pressure and then the temperature caused the coolant to evaporate.